# How to make UserID and ProductID columns as the foreign keys in Downloads Table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

This is what I have done so far !!

---

Create Database **MyWebDB**;

Create Table  **Users**

```
( UserID Int Primary Key,
  EmailAddress Varchar(50) Not Null, 
  FirstName Varchar(50) Not Null, 
  LastName Varchar(50) Not Null)
```

Create Table **Downloads**

```
( DownloadID int Primary Key, 
  DownloadDate SmallDatetime Null, 
  FileNames Varchar(100) Not Null, 
  Foreign Key (UserID) References Users(UserID),
  Foreign Key (ProductID) References Products(ProductID))
```

Create Table **Products**

```
(ProductID int primary key, ProductName Varchar(50))
```

My Sql query

[image]

Comment: ****When I try to make UserID and ProductID as a foreign Keys in Downloads table, I received an error message with red squiggly mark.
Any help is highly appreciated !!

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set data type for Download table UserID and ProductID

```
 Userid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(UserID)
 Productid int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Products(ProductID)
```

or

```
Userid int,
Productid int,
FOREIGN KEY (Userid) REFERENCES Users(UserID),
FOREIGN KEY (Productid) REFERENCES Products(ProductID))
```

Like :

Create Table **Downloads**

```
( DownloadID int Primary Key, 
  DownloadDate SmallDatetime Null, 
  FileNames Varchar(100) Not Null, 
  Userid int,
  Productid int,
  FOREIGN KEY (Userid) REFERENCES Users(UserID),
  FOREIGN KEY (Productid) REFERENCES Products(ProductID))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anoop !!